# Memory error , is there any command to free memory at the end of the program execution?

Tags: python, memory

I am trying to optimize my program, but I can't simplify it anymore. Getting 'Memory Error'

### About program :

I am operating over large amount of data and also using scipy.interpolate for getting the required map at the end for the data. And also have objects which are minimal.

### My problem and the solutions tried:

My program surprisingly do not throw any 'Memory error ' all times , the program runs 8/10 times. Also if i close the environment and run it again, it works perfectly. So I thought I will use something like gc.collect() and it din't help, is there any command for clearing all the memory and variables at the of the program execution , as in Matlab ?? I am new to Python.

Thank you !!

## Setting the basemap and scaling it to the point of interest position

```
m = basemap.Basemap( llcrnrlon = int(rec_long - 15), llcrnrlat = int(rec_lat - 15) ,
                    urcrnrlon = int(rec_long + 15), urcrnrlat = int(rec_lat + 15),   projection='merc', resolution = 'l' ,
                    lat_0 = rec_lat , lon_0 = rec_long )

m.drawcoastlines(ax=ax)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='0.3')
m.fillcontinents(color='gray', lake_color='aqua', ax=ax)
parallels=numpy.linspace(-90,90,6)
m.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[1,1,1,1], fontsize=10)
meridians=numpy.linspace(-180,180,6)
m.drawmeridians(meridians, labels=[1,1,1,1], fontsize=10)
```

## I make grids

grid_x, grid_y = numpy.meshgrid(lx , ly)

## Interpolate IP_magnitude into a grid (x by y dimesions)

```
z = scipy.interpolate.griddata((val_rt_long, val_rt_lat), val_rt_data ,(grid_x,grid_y) ,method='nearest')
```

x , y = m(grid_x, grid_y)

## plotting using pcolormesh the magnitude values

```
m.pcolormesh(x ,y , z, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

cb = m.colorbar(location='bottom',pad='7%')
```

Comment: Can you give a *specific* example case where you run out of memory? "My program surprisingly do not throw any 'Memory error ' all times , the program runs 8/10 times" doesn't really help. Are you running this as a standalone script, or in something like an IPython environment?

Comment: Good question; what I do is restart the kernel and make sure I don't have other memory intensive applications running, but I'd like to know if there is a "clear all" / "cls" type of command in Python.

Comment: "Restart kernel". So you're running inside an IPython environment, possibly through the IPython notebook. Would be good to mention that. You're probably better off creating a stand-alone script and using that for such memory intensive computations: the operating system will clear any memory once the script has finished, and you can run it again without worrying about data remaining in memory.

Comment: Other than that, `del` and `gc.collect()` can help you, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: I run from spyder environment, the python 2.7 is the version i use, my datafile which i process is 6.6 mbytes. I have a main script where i do the general calls to 5 subprograms and set basemap and interpolate and plot, only after i started doing interpolation for over long, lat spanning 30 , 30 degree surfaces, i get this 'Memory error'.... using gc.collect was no help as i mentioned earlier... what is about del ??

Comment: but without problem it works if I close the environment and run it again.....

Comment: most python apps can churn through GB's of data(even if it takes some time) What is your script doing? Can you post the code? What kind of data are you processing? You say you have minimal objects, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Again: write a stand-alone script when you process lots of data. There'll be lots of caching going on in such a development/exploration environment (which get cleared once you close things), and it's not (yet) really useful for processing such large amounts of data. I know tools like matlab and IDL can, and (I)Python will get there, but don't rely on it yet to process large amounts of data.

Comment: @Jeroko If this is a development/exploration environment, and the datafile contains compressed integers that'll blow up to doubles upon read-in, and you're running multiple trials with varying parameter, you can run out memory. Often, output results are cached in special variables (IPython uses `Out[?]` for example), and that may eat up quite a bit of memory in the end.

Comment: It will be huge to run as single script and it is lots of internal processing, so it wont be possible for now to change to single script, it is not readable by the user.....

Comment: By minimal objects , I just mean I don't create lots of objects ...

Comment: @Jeroko , the data i'm processing is from csv file with 6.6mb mainly lon, lat values with magnitudes and time, I have posted the code too

Comment: My question is very simple, I want to know how is it working each time when i close and run the script, what is happening that it works fine??

Comment: ' sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear() ' , will using this command at the end is advisable solution ??

Answer (score 3):

You're running out of memory because your working environment (Spyder) keeps track of some data, despite your attemps with `gc.collect()`. That's what this environment is for: you may want to go back to some earlier results, and it's there, cached by the environment. When you run things multiple times, the memory cache builds up, and eventually becomes full.

When you close Spyder, the operating system frees up all the memory used by Spyder, including all that memory kept around for inspection. That is obvious: there is no way that, once you have closed Spyder, you can retrieve that data from memory: you have to reopen the data file and read in the data, again.

You say it's huge to run as a single script. That doesn't make sense: you show the code in your question, and that's really little, and the lines of code should be the same in Spyder as in a standalone script. Add some imports and you're on your way.

When run standalone, the operating system frees up the used memory every time the script ends. So no data will be cached in memory, and when run multiple times, memory (and data) start with a blank slate.

You mention that you're new to Python, but are used to Matlab. Presumably, you've always run things from the Matlab command line. With Python, try and learn how to write standalone scripts, and run those from the *operating system* (terminal) command line; *not* within a Python development or exploration environment. You can use those environments for quick explorations and trial and error, but for fully fledged data processing, you're better off running standalone scripts.

Comment: thank u for the reply, yes, i don't know how to form a standalone script for now.... And I have lots of import modules and also the program I have pasted is just some lines to give an idea, not lot...